# How can I remove milliseconds from timestamp in oracle insert query using TO_DATE?

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have a value like this '2019-05-04 12:34:20' which I obtain from another database using python code
But when I run the below query in oracle,

```
INSERT INTO sample_table(SCHEDULED_DATE) 
VALUES (TO_DATE('2019-05-04 12:34:20','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

I am getting an output like this,

```
'04-05-19 12:34:20.000000000 PM'
```

What I want is:

```
'2019-05-04 12:34:20'
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are expecting and what you are getting is the same value.

It is just the representation. `SCHEDULED_DATE` is the `timestamp` data type and it shows milliseconds as 000..

You can use `TO_CHAR` to see the value in the format that you want(`to_char(SCHEDULED_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`). and anyway you are adding `date` into `timestamp` so your `timestamp` will always have 000.. in the millisecond.

Comment: Hi Tejash. Presently you have 1,175 instances of the word "cheers" in your answers. Are you aware that we prefer not to add thanks, signatures and other chatty material? That is a lot of repair work for volunteers.

Comment: I do greet the people with Cheers, I don't think there is any harm in it. I will take care of it from next time.

Comment: You could argue the case for non-technical writing on _Meta Stack Overflow_ if you wish, but I am certain it would be unpopular (these discussions have been had a lot already). If an editor were to edit out five of these every day, it would take them around eight months. I appreciate you changing course, but it would be even better if you would help with the historical repair.